# Refspec to disambiguate local and remote tags as well as branches with same name?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-tag

Assume I have a working copy with a tag `1.2.3` and two remotes `origin` and `fork` also with a tag `1.2.3` each, but all three actually point to different commits. In addition, there is a branch `1.2.3` in all of them.

Is there a fully qualified path (refspec) that allows you to refer to the `1.2.3` tag as known by `fork` (or likewise `origin`)?

`git checkout 1.2.3` will switch to the local `1.2.3` branch, and `git checkout tags/1.2.3` to the local `1.2.3` tag. But is it possible to checkout the remote tag `1.2.3` of `fork` somehow? I tried things like `git checkout fork/tags/1.2.3` and `git checkout refs/remotes/fork/tags/1.2.3` (pathspec error), as well as `git checkout refs/remotes/fork/1.2.3` but it checks out the branch of that name, not the tag.

Fetching tags fails:

```
git fetch --tags
From https://...
 ! [rejected]          1.2.3      -> 1.2.3  (would clobber existing tag)
```

Is this a hint that it's not supported by Git?

Comment: Having the "same" (as in "same name") tag on different commits (in different versions of the same project) is the sign of some history break between the different repos. This is not a typical situation, and is likely the result of force-pushes.

Comment: @RomainValeri It doesn't require any force-pushes. The owner of `origin` created a tag, the owner of `fork` created a tag with the same name. You pull from both - you see both tags. Unfortunately, git does not isolate tags by remote, so you have exactly this problem if two remotes disagree on the value of a tag.

Comment: Right, Git is decentralized and it's well possible that a tags with the same names are introduced without knowing about the other until you fetch again... @RaymondChen Does that mean that there is no refspec for remote tags? Is it possible to `git show` the remote tag information nonetheless or do I have to overwrite my local tag with the remote version in any case?

Comment: @CoDEmanX There is no refspec for remote tags, but you can manually pull a remote tag to a new name if you want. `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.2.3:refs/tags/origin-1.2.3` fetches tag `1.2.3` from `origin` and saves it locally as tag `origin-1.2.3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike with branches, Git doesn't namespace tags per remote. If you fetch tags from any remote, they are stored in the `refs/tags/` namespace, akin to `refs/heads/` for your local branches. There is no equivalent to the `refs/remotes/<remote>/` namespace for remote branches.

All of the included tools to work with tags work directly with `refs/tags/`, so even if you decided to manually fetch some remote's tag into a different namespace (as explained in one of the comments on your question), actually *using* them would be fairly uncomfortable. You can do this if you want to checkout some remote's tags without actually having them available as proper tags, though.

It's kind of assumed that people work together when tagging things. If you can't avoid multiple people creating the same tag with different contents, you may need to agree on a tag naming scheme (e.g. foo-1.1.2 and bar-1.1.2) or not use tags at all.